# Why the same prop is array in parent component and isn't array anymore if passed to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component:

```
class SuppliersPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const suppliersList = this.props.suppliers.map(supplier => (
      <ListRow name={supplier.name} key={supplier.id} />
    ));

    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-4">
          <div className="Section boxed rounded">
            <ButtonNew />
            {
              this.props.ui.list.loading ? 'loading' :
              <table className="table table-hover table-condensed">
                <tbody>
                  { suppliersList }
                </tbody>
              </table>
            }
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-8">
          <div className="Section boxed rounded">
            <Form />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It works well: when `this.props.ui.list.loading` is `true` it shows "loading" while when `this.props.ui.list.loading` becomes `false` it shows the list of suppliers.

Now, I'd like to extract the `suppliersList` into its own components having in the end three components:

1. `SuppliersPage`
2. `List`
3. `ListRow`

So I do this:

```
// Page.jsx

class SuppliersPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-4">
          <div className="Section boxed rounded">
            <ButtonNew />
            {this.props.ui.list.loading ? 'loading' : <List suppliers={this.props.suppliers} />}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-8">
          <div className="Section boxed rounded">
            <Form />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have removed all the logic that creates the list of suppliers and that renders the table with it.

I've moved all this logic in `List.jsx` that is this:

```
// List.jsx
export default (suppliers) => {
  const suppliersList = suppliers.map(supplier => (
    <ListRow name={supplier.name} key={supplier.id} />
  ));

  return (
    <table className="table table-hover table-condensed">
      <tbody>
        { suppliersList }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

Nothing complex: I simply process the array of `this.props.suppliers` directly in the `List` component.

But here comes the problem: running this code throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: suppliers.map is not a function
>       at ./assets/components/Business/Suppliers/List.jsx.exports.default (List.jsx:5)

**So, practically, it seems to me that if I do `this.props.suppliers.map(...)` in the `Page` component all works well, while if I pass `this.props.suppliers` to the child component `List` and do the same the passed value is not array anymore.**

**Any ideas about what is going on and how to solve the problem?**

I really don't understand why in `Page` no error is thrown while it is thrown in the child component: the value should ever be the same, but it seems that I'm missing something in my thoughts.

Can you help me to better understand what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first argument to `List.jsx` is a props hash, which of course has no function property named `map` just like the error message is saying.  assuming you're trying to use object shorthand in your function args, you need to add some curly braces:

```
// List.jsx
export default ({suppliers}) => {
// ...
```

Comment: Perfect! It works now! can you give some links where I can better understand this difference?

Comment: [Functional and Class Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components), from the React docs, is a good place to start.

Comment: I think now I'm understanding: practically using {} I'm destructuring the `props` passed to the child component: am I right?

Comment: yep!  by using `{}` you're destructuring the component props, and by using `suppliers` instead of `suppliers: suppliers` you're using [object shorthand](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand).